# How to zoom in and zoom out Images in WP7?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have made an application which displays Images .Now I want to implement zoom in and zoom out feature(by using two fingertip's) as in native windows phone photo viewer application.Any idea on how to proceed .

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: two good options offered so far

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Perhaps the most expedient approach would be to include the [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034).  This contains a `GestureService` that will help with pinch and rotate touch gestures.  You could apply it to an image like this:-

```
 <Image Source="someSourceUrl" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
     <Image.RenderTransform>
         <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
     </Image.RenderTransform>
     <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <toolkit:GestureListener PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" />
     </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
 </Image>
```

Then in code-behind:-

```
    private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        initialAngle = transform.Rotation;
        initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
    }

    private void OnPinchDelta(object sender, PinchGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        transform.Rotation = initialAngle + e.TotalAngleDelta;
        transform.ScaleX = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
        transform.ScaleY = initialScale * e.DistanceRatio;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i am dynamically loading images in code.So is it possible to do the above procedure completely in code?

Comment: @Vaysage:  You can still use this with dynamically loaded images.  Typically with dynamic images you would assign a new instance of `BitmapImage` to the `Source` property of the existing `Image` control rather than unloading and loading instances of an `Image` element.   It would be at this point that you would also set the Rotation on the transform to 0 as well as the ScaleX and ScaleY to 1.

Comment: I extended this with drag control, and now I am able to drag the image out of the window (both with drag and pinch) any ideas how to awoid this?

Comment: Just curious. Where are "initialScale" and "initialAngle" defined and what types are they?

Comment: @Pretzel:  You would define them as fields in the host Page and they would be the same type as `Rotation` and `ScaleX` respectively, doubles I think.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out. They are indeed Doubles. Thanks! :)

Comment: Could you also use this when there are Paths defined ( to get some elements on the image clickabe )?

Comment: The GestureListener has been removed in the latest version http://phone.codeplex.com/releases/view/96743

Comment: Odd enought is still available in that version

Comment: This is not a good solution, because the scale centers on the center of the image, if you select two points with your fingers and pinch, those two points are not beneath your fingers in the end.

Answer (score 5):

Check out Laurent Bugnion's multitouch sample - http://multitouch.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

if you want simple image viewer that supports multi-touch, I recommend you to use `WebBrowser` control to display image.

It supports multi-touch zoom and smooth scrolling as well by default. But you must have to copy file to isolated storage from project folder. Here's how I've done:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <phone:WebBrowser 
        Name="MyWebBrowserControl"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" />
</Grid>
```

---

```
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

        // if image file does not exist in isolated storage, copy it to there~!
        if (!isf.FileExists(filename))
        {
            StreamResourceInfo sr = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.Stream))
            {
                byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)sr.Stream.Length);

                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isf.OpenFile(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)))
                {
                    bw.Write(data);
                    bw.Close();
                }

                br.Close();
            }
        }

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { MyWebBrowserControl.Navigate(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative)); });
```

※ You must set the **Build Action** of image file to **Content**

Comment: I have no proof, but I believe the WebBrowser control would a be a resource intensive control to use if you were only using it to view an image. That said, if it gets the job done...

Comment: @DanielBallinger // I already made application and published(with this way). Of course, I know there is pros and cons. It's very easy to implement zoom-able image viewer while it could be resource-intensive. Decision is yours.

Comment: This is a valid approach for some use cases and doesn't deserve to be dismissed out of hand.