# WP7 pinch and zoom image in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678268/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-images-in-wp7) example of ping/zoom of images and seems pretty straight forward.

The problem I'm having is that my image is part of the data template of my pivot control and I am unable to access the transform object.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Name="displayImage" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="{Binding photo_link}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="transform" />
        </Image.RenderTransform>
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta" PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted" />
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    </Image>
</DataTemplate>
```

In this method, `transform` cannot be resolved.

```
private void OnPinchStarted(object sender, PinchStartedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    initialAngle =  transform.Rotation;
    initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
}
```

any ideas??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sender should be the Image that the listener is attached to:

```
var image = sender as Image;
var transform = image.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;

initialAngle = transform.Rotation;
initialScale = transform.ScaleX;
```