# Double multiplication giving NaN

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to use manipulation to rescale a canvas. On debugging the below code it seems that canImage.Width and canImage.Heigh both get set to `NaN`. I don't understand how a double times a double can give `Nan`

> (width ~ 400 Height ~400 e.scale.y ~-1.5 e.Scale.X ~0.3)

.

```
    private void viewer_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X != 0 && e.TotalManipulation.Scale.Y != 0) {
            canImage.Width = mainImage.Width * (double)e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X;
            canImage.Height = mainImage.Height * (double)e.TotalManipulation.Scale.Y;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Just put a conditional breakpoint in and it seems `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X` and `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X` are never `NaN`. Putting the `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X > 0` condition did stop the issue. It looks like setting Height/Width to something less than one just causes them to become NaN rather than just falling over. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Have you confirmed neither `mainImage.Width` nor `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X` are `NaN`?

Comment: Had this issue and the Manipulation.Scale.X values were NaN. There's great code here from when I asked this question, see the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507416/constraints-on-image-width-height-on-wp7-gesturelistener

Comment: Why the `(double)` typecasts?

Comment: Because I thought multiplying was the issue so I wanted to be sure it was the correct type. Just clutching at straws really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that negative sign supposed to be there for e.scale.y = -1.5?
Setting the height to a negative number may explain your problems.

Answer (score 1):

If `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X` or `e.TotalManipulation.Scale.Y` are equal to `NaN`, then the product will be equal to `NaN`. Try testing using the following instead (since you wouldn't want negative numbers either):

```
if (e.TotalManipulation.Scale.X > 0 && e.TotalManipulation.Scale.Y > 0)
```

Comment: @Greg That's not how you check for NaN. You should either compare a number to itself (by definition NaNs are not equal to any number, including another NaN) or use `Double.IsNaN`

Comment: @Praetorian - It **does** work. I just tested it: `(Double.NaN > 0)` returns false. This is a fine approach because the OP should also reject negative numbers.

Comment: You should add a comment though. That this code is intended to cope with NaN and rejects them.

Comment: @Greg It may work, but if you read the [IEEE 754 spec](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/NaN) on NaN, the equality test is the only one guaranteed to not throw an exception. Other comparisons will throw an exception if the NaN happens to be a signalling NaN.