# Can Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 do image zooming?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1.1

Can Windows Phone SDK 7.1.1 do image zooming? Like for example, the phone app is about a product store. So customer decides to view the product in a zoom-in version. I have research on the net but to no avail. And i know that maps can be zoom in. Does the image zooming works like that too?

Comment: Did you try [this](http://www.frenk.com/2011/03/windows-phone-7-correct-pinch-zoom-in-silverlight/) ?

Answer (score 0):

In [Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/55034), you have part which name's `GestureService`, and it have probably what you need. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678268/how-to-zoom-in-and-zoom-out-images-in-wp7) shows how to use it by example.